# Flutter analyze / build fails in GitHub action

Tags: flutter, github-actions

When the following action is run, it fails on `flutter analyze`. If I remove it, it fails later on `flutter build`. Both commands work fine locally. I understand the message, but fail to grasp what might be wrong with the package path.

GitHub action error:

```
  flutter analyze
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    JAVA_HOME_12.0.2_x64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/12.0.2/x64
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/12.0.2/x64
    JAVA_HOME_12_0_2_X64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/12.0.2/x64
    FLUTTER_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/1.22.5-stable/x64
Analyzing myApp...                                            

  error • Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:myApp/app.dart' • lib/main.dart:7:8 • uri_does_not_exist
  error • The function 'App' isn't defined • lib/main.dart:38:16 • undefined_function

2 issues found. (ran in 18.4s)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Action source:

```
name: Flutter Android Test and Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build_android:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: "12.x"
      - name: Setup Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          flutter-version: "1.22.5"
      - name: Install Flutter dependencies
        run: flutter pub get
      - name: Format files
        run: flutter format --set-exit-if-changed .
      - name: Analyze code
        run: flutter analyze
      - name: Run tests
        run: flutter test
      - name: Build Android
        run: flutter build apk
```

Comment: All files available in the repository? Maybe you not commited `lib/main.dart`?

Comment: Thanks @fartem for pointing me in the right direction. The file was on GitHub, but I noticed a lower / upper case typo in the file name. It was working locally since OSX's filesystem is case insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in a upper case / lower case file name typo. OSX filesystem is by default case insensitive, while Ubuntu, on which the GitHub Action runs, is not.

Comment: So how should one name the files?

Comment: As long as this question concerns, name in import statements need to be the same case as the actual file names. I think I made this mistake early in the development when refactoring files and could not spot the bug since it ran smoothly for a good few months on OSX.

Comment: Actually nowadays Flutter Lint will by default enforce lower_case_with_underscores file names for consistency and better platform compatibility. Problem solved.

Comment: I am on `Flutter 2.5.1` where the `flutter_lints` comes by default while creating a project. I have a flutter package project and it has two example projects inside the `examples` folder as the flutter docs suggested. When I ran `flutter analyze` locally, there was not any problem, the process went smoothly. But at GitHub action, `flutter analyze` starting to fail and the log was **error • Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:paginablelistviewbuilder_example/utils.dart' • examples/paginablelistviewbuilder_example/lib/main.dart:4:8 • uri_does_not_exist** Can you help with this?

Comment: I am afraid I can't, no idea what might be happening. Maybe post it as a separate question along with the actual output. Hopefully there will be someone smarter than me...

Comment: I had solved it by performing `flutter pub get` inside the example projects.

Answer (score 6):

Passing `--no-fatal-infos` and `--no-fatal-warnings` as a flag to flutter analyzer worked for me.

Here: `flutter analyze --no-fatal-infos --no-fatal-warnings`

This is because, unlike dart analyzer, flutter analyzer returns a fatal exit code of 1 regardless of the severity issue (info, warning, error).

[Reference](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/61589)

Comment: This looks like it should work but it actually does nothing for me. The analyser still tanks.