# flutter analyze works on local but fails in github actions

Tags: flutter, dart, github-actions, lint

Im using [lint](https://pub.dev/packages/lint) in my flutter project and i applied some rules in my **analysis_options.yaml** that works on local as i expected, but when my workflow on github actions is excecuted (with the same exact code) flutter analyze fails and show me 2 new problems like this one:

```
 "info • Prefer const over final for declarations • lib/data/remote/user_api_provider.dart:146:7 • prefer_const_declarations
"
```

on local "flutter analyze" it cant detect it.

im very confused, i cant find information on google i dont know how to solve this.

Im using Flutter 2.2.2 stable and dart 2.13.3 stable.

Edit:
This is my workflow

```
name: Lint-Analyze

on:  
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  flutter_analyze:
    name: Run flutter analyze
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: "12.x"
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          flutter-version: '2.2.2'
          channel: 'stable'

      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter analyze
```

Comment: Are you using the same `analysis_options.yaml` file in both places?  is the version of Flutter and Dart the same?

Comment: @jamesdlin yeah, the same file.

Comment: Same problem :( no solution

Comment: I have shared what worked for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70056450/9988524).

Answer (score 1):

I think your Flutter version in the GitHub action is not on the same version you use locally.

Please check your workflow file for something like this:

```
  with: flutter-version: '2.0.5'
```

And run `flutter doctor` on your local machine to check if the versions are really the same. If not, just change the version of your GitHub action.

Hope that's fixes your issue :)

Comment: i was thinking the same but when i added the same version the error still happen u.u

Comment: Can you provide your GitHub workflow in your question? Maybe that could give us a hint.